# What is this Easter egg referring to?

Tags: medievil-2019

What is this thing? It's in the second run of the graveyard (where you fight the wolves boss) in the Medievil PS4 remake. I'm not able to get to it, hit it or interact with it. It looks like a watermelon wearing a hat and smiling at me.

[image: screenshot]

**Update**: Further along in the game, I've found another one that is easily accessible, but there is no interaction with it. It's a static object. I did find some potential answers in a few Reddit posts stating that they are Easter eggs, but they did not specify as to what.

[image: screenshot (Scarecrow Fields)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Easter Egg the reddit users are referring to is [Mr. Apple](https://gallowmere.fandom.com/wiki/Mr_Apple). [Paul Donovan](https://gallowmere.fandom.com/wiki/Paul_Donovan), who claims he was a developer of the game, wrote the following in response to an email

> The apple wearing a red origami hat pictured in the credits is Mr Apple. He was an apple that I bought for lunch one day which Matt Johnson (programmer) nicked and kept on his desk. Katie Lea (mapper) made him a paper hat. He lasted about 9 months without rotting due to the magical powers of the hat. Something to do with pyramids I guess..

Answer (score 1):

This [SCE Studio Cambridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCE_Studio_Cambridge) "mascot" carries over from the original 1998 PS1 game — only present in the end credits to my knowledge:

[image: credits screenshot]

> This game is dedicate to the memory of Mr Apple. If only we'd never removed his magic hat.
>
> ©1998 Sony Computer Entertainment Europe